# unescaped apostrophe in string

Tags: android, aapt

I have searched alot, but nowhere found the answer/solution for following:

In Android Studio, I hava a project that works without problems for many years. After updating in 'build.grandle' file compileSdkVersion to '28', buildToolsVersion to '28.0.2' and targetSdkVersion to '28', it is not possible to become a clean build due to:

*error: **unescaped apostrophe in string**
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: unescaped apostrophe in string, sources=[/home/.../app/src/main/res/values/arrays.xml:77:5-89:20], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}*

*error: **could not parse array item.**
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: could not parse array item., sources=[/home/.../app/src/main/res/values/arrays.xml:77:5-89:20], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}*

A lot of similar questions exist on the web handling the apostrophe problem, but in my case, there is no apostrophe in 'arrays.xml:77:5-89:20':

```
...
77    <string-array name="textFontSizeValues">
78        <item>0</item>
79        <item>1</item>
80        <item>2</item>
81        <item>3</item>
82        <item>4</item>
83        <item>5</item>
84        <item>6</item>
85        <item>7</item>
86        <item>8</item>
87        <item>9</item>
88        <item>10</item>
89    </string-array>
...
```

Edit:
Also having only

```
...
<string-array name="textFontSizeValues">
</string-array>
...
```

gives the same errors, which does not make sense for me as there is no "apostrophe"

Comment: Any chance that you copy-pasted this code from somewhere? There are often unicode/linebreak characters you can't see in the AS editor.

Comment: Not that I know. I have also tried to copy the working string-array above, from the same file, which has not that problem.. But it doesn't help...

Comment: Make a backup copy of `values.xml`, or ensure that your current version is in version control. Delete all of the `<item>` elements from the `textFontSizeValues` array. Then try to build the APK and see if the compile error goes away. If it does, then there really is something fishy with those `<item>` elements, and it may be simplest just to re-key them in. If the compile error remains, restore your backed-up `values.xml`... and I'm not sure where to go from there (beyond the standard "Build > Clean Project" recommendation).

Comment: Beyond that... why do you need an array of **strings**, if it contains **integers**?

Comment: Where to find the "values.xml" file? I haven't found it... I deleted all the `<item>` elements from the `textFontSizeValues` array, and tried a new "Build > Clean Project" which still does not successfully compile due to the same errors (this time only the line numbers info is different) :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already found the solution but just in case.

I had the same error and found the wrong apostrophe , but in your case is weird as it seems you only have numbers.

I would do the same as i did: Delete all items in the array, check if you don´t get the error and write one by one manually without copy and paste. its a short code so you could manage.

Good luck!